# Javascript como saber cuando termina un bucle

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estimados tengo una aplicación web en la cual tengo un cuadro con maestros los cuales van a pertenecer a un grupo.

Mi problema es que no se como hacer para avisar que se grabo el grupo correctamente y recargar la pagina.

Yo hago lo siguiente

```js
function GuardoTodo(){
var variable_post=$("#grupo").val();    //<-el nombre del grupo
var claveingresado=0;  
/// Invocamos a nuestro script PHP
$.post("grabo-grupo.php", { variable: variable_post }, function(data){
/// Ponemos la respuesta de nuestro script en el DIV recargado
 $("#recargado").html("Guardando Grupo");  
 claveingresado=data;  //<- ese el id del grupo guardado

    //recorro los maestros seleccionados
 $("#listamaestros li").each(function(){
  var variable_post=claveingresado+","+$(this).attr('id');
  $.post("grabo-grupo-docentes.php", { variable: variable_post }, function(data){
   /// Ponemos la respuesta de nuestro script en el DIV recargado
    $("#recargado").html("Guardando docente al grupo");  
   });
 });
   location.reload();

});

}
```

el tema es que si hay por ejemplo 50 maestros del grupo solo graba 11, porque no le da tiempo a terminar de recorrer el li, si saco la linea location.reload(); graba todo perfecto, pero claro queda la pantalla sin refrescarse, lo que quisiera hacer es que cuando termine el bucle se recargue correctamente.
gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Hola! Espero esto te ayude:

```js
function GuardoTodo(){
var variable_post=$("#grupo").val();    //<-el nombre del grupo
var claveingresado=0;  
/// Invocamos a nuestro script PHP
$.post("grabo-grupo.php", { variable: variable_post }, function(data){
/// Ponemos la respuesta de nuestro script en el DIV recargado
 $("#recargado").html("Guardando Grupo");  
 claveingresado=data;  //<- ese el id del grupo guardado
    var totalMaestros = $("#listamaestros li").length;
    var procesadosMaestros = 0;
 $("#listamaestros li").each(function(){
  var variable_post=claveingresado+","+$(this).attr('id');

        //recorro los maestros seleccionados
  $.post("grabo-grupo-docentes.php", { variable: variable_post }, function(data){
   /// Ponemos la respuesta de nuestro script en el DIV recargado
    $("#recargado").html("Guardando docente al grupo");
                procesadosMaestros++;
                if(procesadosMaestros >= totalMaestros)location.reload();
 
   });
 });

});

}
```

¡Saludos!

Comment: Gracias Sebastian !